# Does Webpack process index.html for Vue apps?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, single-page-application, assets

In my index.html, I have these inside of the `head` tag:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="./assets/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./assets/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="./assets/manifest.json">
```

However, whenever index.html is loaded, those assets just load as index.html again and not their images. Does Webpack not process index.html? Is there some other way to get processed content into the `head` tag? Or do I have to put these in the `static` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put these in the `static` folder - the reason is that the only treatment that `index.html` receives from Webpack (as configured in the official Vue template) is to inject the resulting JS and CSS files. It simply ignores your existing references to assets. So you have several choices:

1. Continue using the official Webpack template from Vue and store your static assets in `/static`, then references them manually in `index.html` using paths which refer to your deployment - not to your development environment
2. Use your assets in one or more Vue single-file components - then their relative URLs will be processed by Vue-loader and properly included in your bundle. In this case you do not have to manually include them in `index.html`
3. Use the [html-webpack-include-assets-plugin](https://github.com/jharris4/html-webpack-include-assets-plugin) for the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) - the latter is already used by the official Vue template to inject JS and CSS into `index.html` You will have to modify your `/build/webpack.prod.conf.js` and configure the above plugin - look at its examples on GitHub

And to answer your question - the only way to get hash versioning and compression is to refer to your assets from a Vue component using relative path so that they are properly treated by Vue-loader.

Comment: Can you explain why? And if I have to put them in the static folder, would it be possible to still the benefits of webpack (like a version hash at the end or compression if possible, removing white space, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the details. This makes more sense. For #2, is it possible to include things like that in a component? I would think things in the header like favicon should actually be in the source of the page.

Comment: Sure, favicon should reside in the index.html - you are advised to use option (1) in this case.